# How to change the default selected value for the radio group in wicket

Tags: java, wicket

I have a radio group in my application,and I have to change the default selected value of the radio buttons,how can we do that in wicket?

```
<wicket:container wicket:id="sign in">
                        <div class="col-25">
                            <label class="radio-inline"> <input
                                wicket:id="signInYes" type="radio" name="ticker" checked="checked"  />Yes
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-25">
                            <label class="radio-inline"> <input
                                wicket:id="signInNo" type="radio" name="ticker" />No
                            </label>
                        </div>

                    </wicket:container>
```

Comment: Please provide an example, and what have you tried so far.

Comment: And please start accepting the answers of your previous questions. Otherwise we won't help you anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All `FormComponent`s use their model object as the `selected value`. You can provide the value in the IModel passed to the constructor, e.g. `RadioChoice(String id, IModel<T> model, List<? extends T> choices)` or `RadioGroup(String id, IModel<T> model)`.

You can also pass it after instantiation with `formComponent.setModel(aNewModel)` or `formComponent.setModelObject(aNewModelObject)`

In your case I think you use RadioGroup and Radio components. So the model object of the RadioGroup must have the same value as the model object of the Radio that should be selected.

Comment: If you give an example ,it would be helpful,since I am new to wicket I don't understand it